# Apply eslint rules in Next JS while compilation time

Tags: next.js, eslint

I created an application in NextJs. I have my eslint configuration:

```js
{
  "extends": "next/core-web-vitals",
  "rules": {
    "react/no-unescaped-entities": "off",
    "@next/next/no-page-custom-font": "off",
    "prefer-const": "warn"
  }
}
```

The rules are aplied when i run `npm run lint`, but i need to apply the rules when i type the code in the editor like when i will type this line: `let a = 2;` to get the warning at once in my editor. `Warning: 'a' is never reassigned. Use 'const' instead.  prefer-const`.
 Question: What configuration i need to add to get what i described above?

Comment: First, what editor are you using? It'll be difficult to recommend a setting/plugin without that information.